# How to avoid `Call to undefined function` fatal error in a custom PHP file for WordPress

Tags: php, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming, advanced-custom-fields

We're in **WordPress**. We're trying to make a customizable **CSS** style sheet. Using **Advanced Custom Fields** plugin, we've created a custom field called *color*. We'll use it as an option to define a color value, in HEX format, as used in CSS.

We've created a PHP file just to be used as CSS style sheet. It's loaded from our WordPress as a CSS resource. This PHP produces a CSS code where we want to use our color option as color property for some elements.

But, here is the problem, that PHP generates this error:

> **Fatal error**:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function the_field()...

This is the PHP code:

```
<?php
header('Content-type: text/css');
the_field('primary_theme_color', 'option');
$color = the_field('primary_theme_color', 'option');
?>
:root {
    --primary-color:<?php echo $color; ?>;
}
* {
    background-color: var(--primary-color);
}
```

We know that `the_field()` function exists inside Advanced Custom Fields plugin, so why it doesn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error info can't be clearer: you are pretending to use a function that is not defined. This function is `the_field()`, and yes, this is a known function from **Advanced Custom Fields** plugin for WordPress, but this is what it happens:

You have made a PHP script to generate a CSS style sheet. Inside this script, you need to use `the_field()` function. This script **runs as standalone**, so, when you try to use that function, it doesn't declared. **You need to *load* WordPress before**.

Just add this line **before** invoke `the_field()` function:

```
require_once 'pathToYourWordPressRootDir/wp-blog-header.php';
```

Of course, you need to replace `pathToYourWordPressRootDir` with correct value. For example, if your PHP file is inside `wp-content/themes/yourTheme/assets/common/`, then it will be:

```
require_once '../../../../../../wp-blog-header.php';
```

Or, more reliable:

```
require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/../../../../../../wp-blog-header.php';
```

**Note**.- In many posts, you can find that the way to load WordPress is requiring `wp-load.php` instead of `wp-blog-header.php`. But I guess `wp-load.php` is heavier, so I prefer `wp-blog-header.php`, and I tried yet using it and it works fine!

**Remember**.- Advanced Custom Fields plugin must be installed and active.

#### Important

The function `the_field()` doesn't return anything, just does an echo of `get_field()`. So, to get the value you want, you need to use `get_field()` function:

```
$color = get_field('primary_theme_color', 'option');
```